# Securing assets on Microsoft Azure CDN (Verizon Premium) using token authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, token, cdn

I am attempting to secure files in one folder on Verizon Premium CDN using token authentication. I have followed the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth).

I have successfully installed the PHP module that encrypts requests and it is working correctly in my application, tested against the encrypt/decrypt tool in the Azure Portal.

I have set up a rule in the rules engine on the CDN endpoint, but when I access the files directly on the CDN endpoint they are not locked or secured and do not require any token key to load them. I am not sure if I have missed something, or if my Rules Engine rule is wrong. My custom rule in the rules engine is set up with this logic:

If 'URL Path Directory' 'matches' '/assets/v1/' then 'enable' 'Token Authentication', 'ignore case', relative to 'root' (the other option rather than root would be 'origin').

Have I got the path wrong? Am I missing some regular expression detail?

The only similar questions here on SO have not successfully dealt with this question and have just talked about privacy options on blobs/containers etc. I originally tried all the same setup on an Azure Storage using a container and blobs but these did not get secured in any way either. I have now set it up to get the files from the web application web site instead. I am quite happy to set it up whichever way works best.

Comment: Hello KJP, i don't know much about azure cdn but if '/assets/v1/' is meant to be a regex pattern then you're matching only '/assets/v1/'. If you need to secure ressources inside this path maybe a pattern like '/assets/v1/.*' is better

Comment: @Mumrah81, thanks but it's matching a 'directory path' rather than a 'file path'. I don't think that's it, but I'll give it a go and see what happens...

Comment: Yeah I tried this and waited over a day to see if anything changed (rule propagation can take 4 hours or something), no joy with any of it. I have followed the docs precisely. I have no support plan so I'll try to ask for help classing it as a bug.

Comment: Because I'm working on a charity project Microsoft were kind enough to give me some free support on this. I had the path wrong because I didn't understand what the path was relative to, so it was quite simple to fix once that was explained to me. Top marks to MS for being kind enough to help me fix it.